# Voyager admin panel on Laravel 5.3 could not find a storage symlink

Tags: php, laravel, admin, symlink

Help guys: I tried to test the new Laravel admin and got the following error:

> Missing storage symlink We could not find a storage symlink. This
>   could cause problems with loading media files from the browser.

I tried to use:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Set in Nginx config:

```
disable_symlinks off;
```

But it still is not working.

Comment: what two directories are you trying to link? does that link exist?

`man ln`

Answer (score 1):

Delete first the existing storage link in public.
after, re-run (in app path)

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the image issue by editing config/filesystems.php

change the 'public' => root & url value as per your project.. i think it will fix it..

```
 'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('../../public_html/images'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/images',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],

],
```

Answer (score 0):

Having struggled with this symbolic link, here is the procedure:
Once the installation is done on the production server:

```
cd public
rm storage
```

Go to the admin panel of Voyager and click on Fix It. Do not use the PHP command `artisan storage:link.`

Everything works now.